# XSLT: Remove a same attribute from different tags in SVG files

Tags: xslt

How to write an XSLT template to remove the `font-family` attribute from `<g>` or `<text>` tags in **SVG** files ?

```
<text font-family="ComicRelief, ComicRelief" transform="translate(14.17 51.75)">S tars</text>
<g font-family="ComicRelief-Bold, ComicRelief Bold" font-weight="700">
```

Comment: Use `<xsl:template match="text/@font-family | g/@font-family"/>` together with the identity transformation (e.g. in XSLT 3 declared with `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`) and the proper `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` namespace declaration on the root element of the stylesheet or at least on that `xsl:template`. That assumes an XSLT 2 or 3 processor.

Comment: What did you try, what did you find difficult about this task, how did your attempt fail? It's about as simple as XSLT transformation gets.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to utilizing a template that matches all nodes and copies them, create a *empty* template that matches the `font-family` attribute only if they're associated with `g` or `text` element nodes.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <xsl:template match="svg:g/@font-family | svg:text/@font-family"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Notes:**

- SVG files have a namespace(s), they will need to be declared in your stylesheet, i.e. `xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`
- Both the `g` and `text` element nodes can then be referenced using `svg:g` and `svg:text` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your input as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
     <text font-family="ComicRelief, ComicRelief" transform="translate(14.17 51.75)">S tars</text>
     <g font-family="ComicRelief-Bold, ComicRelief Bold" font-weight="700"/>
</Root>
```

You can remove same named attribute from different xml tags like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*/@font-family"/>
```

Which should render to SVG files.
You can refer the transformation [here](http://xsltransform.net/6qaFCEN)

Comment: 1.Your first template is redundant.  2. Your last template will remove **all** occurrences of `font-family` attribute, not just from the two elements requested. Also, the `*/` part in the match pattern is redundant: an attribute must be a child of an element. 3. That's not what an SVG document looks like.

Comment: 1. Agreed. That can be removed. 2. I took it as **all** different tags (as mentioned in headline). 3. I know SVG doesn't look like but the asker hasn't given that part of xslt transformation. so I gave it as an example to use that `template ` in his/her code.